# Local Airflow Instance with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, airflow, minikube

I'm trying to run local Airflow instance on my laptop using `minikube`, `deployment.yml` file with the following command: `kubectl apply -f ./deployment.yml`.

After slightly tweaking this file I was able to end up with all three pods: `postgres`, `webserver`, `scheduler` running fine.

[The result of the `kubectl get pods`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kq7l.jpg)

The content of the file:

```
---
# Source: airflow/templates/rbac/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: release-name-airflow
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
automountServiceAccountToken: true
---
# Source: airflow/charts/postgresql/templates/secrets.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: release-name-postgresql
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    helm.sh/chart: postgresql-11.0.6
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "**************"
  # We don't auto-generate LDAP password when it's not provided as we do for other passwords
---
# Source: airflow/templates/config/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: release-name-airflow
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: Opaque
data:
  airflow-password: "*************"
  # Airflow keys must be base64-encoded, hence we need to pipe to 'b64enc' twice
  # The auto-generation mechanism available at "common.secrets.passwords.manage" isn't compatible with encoding twice
  # Therefore, we can only use this function if the secret already exists
  airflow-fernet-key: "TldwdU0zRklTREZ0VDFkamVWUjFaMlozWTFKdWNFNUxTRXRxVm5Oa1p6az0="
  airflow-secret-key: "VldWaWQySkhSVUZQZDNWQlltbG1UVzUzVkdwWmVVTkxPR1ZCZWpoQ05tUT0="
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: airflow-dependencies
  namespace: "default"
data:
  requirements.txt: |-
    apache-airflow==2.2.3 
    pytest==6.2.4 
    python-slugify<5.0 
    funcy==1.16 
    apache-airflow-providers-mongo 
    apache-airflow-providers-postgres 
    apache-airflow-providers-slack
    apache-airflow-providers-amazon
    airflow_clickhouse_plugin
    apache-airflow-providers-sftp
    surveymonkey-python
---
# Source: airflow/templates/rbac/role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: release-name-airflow
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - "pods"
    verbs:
      - "create"
      - "list"
      - "get"
      - "watch"
      - "delete"
      - "patch"
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - "pods/log"
    verbs:
      - "get"
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - "pods/exec"
    verbs:
      - "create"
      - "get"
---
# Source: airflow/templates/rbac/rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: release-name-airflow
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: release-name-airflow
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: release-name-airflow
    namespace: default
---
# Source: airflow/charts/postgresql/templates/primary/svc-headless.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: release-name-postgresql-hl
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    helm.sh/chart: postgresql-11.0.6
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
    # Use this annotation in addition to the actual publishNotReadyAddresses
    # field below because the annotation will stop being respected soon but the
    # field is broken in some versions of Kubernetes:
    # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58662
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  # We want all pods in the StatefulSet to have their addresses published for
  # the sake of the other Postgresql pods even before they're ready, since they
  # have to be able to talk to each other in order to become ready.
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  ports:
    - name: tcp-postgresql
      port: 5432
      targetPort: tcp-postgresql
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
---
# Source: airflow/charts/postgresql/templates/primary/svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: release-name-postgresql
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    helm.sh/chart: postgresql-11.0.6
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
  annotations:
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: tcp-postgresql
      port: 5432
      targetPort: tcp-postgresql
      nodePort: null
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
---
# Source: airflow/templates/web/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: release-name-airflow
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      nodePort: 30303
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/component: web
---
# Source: airflow/templates/scheduler/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-airflow-scheduler
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: scheduler
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
      app.kubernetes.io/component: scheduler
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate: {}
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
        helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: scheduler
      annotations:
        checksum/configmap: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
    spec:

      affinity:
        podAffinity:

        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
                    app.kubernetes.io/component: scheduler
                namespaces:
                  - "default"
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 1
        nodeAffinity:

      serviceAccountName: release-name-airflow
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      initContainers:

      containers:

        - name: airflow-scheduler
          image: "docker.io/bitnami/airflow-scheduler:2.2.3-debian-10-r57"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1001
          env:
            - name: AIRFLOW_FERNET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-airflow
                  key: airflow-fernet-key
            - name: AIRFLOW_SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-airflow
                  key: airflow-secret-key
            - name: AIRFLOW_LOAD_EXAMPLES
              value: "no"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_NAME
              value: "bitnami_airflow"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_USERNAME
              value: "bn_airflow"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-postgresql
                  key: password
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_HOST
              value: "release-name-postgresql"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER
              value: "5432"

            - name: AIRFLOW_EXECUTOR
              value: LocalExecutor
            - name: AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_HOST
              value: release-name-airflow
            - name: AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_PORT_NUMBER
              value: "8080"
            - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER
              value: /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
            - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING
              value: "True"
            - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__DONOT_PICKLE
              value: "False"
          resources:
            limits: {}
            requests: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /bitnami/python/requirements.txt
              name: requirements
              subPath: requirements.txt
            - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/src
              name: airflow-dags

      volumes:
        - name: requirements
          configMap:
            name: airflow-dependencies
        - name: airflow-dags
          hostPath:
            # directory location on host
            path: /Users/admin/Desktop/FXC_Airflow/dags/src
            # this field is optional
            type: Directory
---
# Source: airflow/templates/web/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-airflow-web
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
    helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
      app.kubernetes.io/component: web
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate: {}
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
        helm.sh/chart: airflow-12.0.5
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: web
      annotations:
        checksum/configmap: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
    spec:

      affinity:
        podAffinity:

        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: airflow
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
                    app.kubernetes.io/component: web
                namespaces:
                  - "default"
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 1
        nodeAffinity:

      serviceAccountName: release-name-airflow
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      initContainers:

      containers:

        - name: airflow-web
          image: docker.io/bitnami/airflow:2.2.3-debian-10-r62
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1001
          env:
            - name: AIRFLOW_FERNET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-airflow
                  key: airflow-fernet-key
            - name: AIRFLOW_SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-airflow
                  key: airflow-secret-key
            - name: AIRFLOW_LOAD_EXAMPLES
              value: "no"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_NAME
              value: "bitnami_airflow"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_USERNAME
              value: "bn_airflow"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-postgresql
                  key: password
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_HOST
              value: "release-name-postgresql"
            - name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER
              value: "5432"

            - name: AIRFLOW_EXECUTOR
              value: LocalExecutor
            - name: AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_HOST
              value: "0.0.0.0"
            - name: AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_PORT_NUMBER
              value: "8080"
            - name: AIRFLOW_USERNAME
              value: airflow
            - name: AIRFLOW_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-airflow
                  key: airflow-password
            - name: AIRFLOW_BASE_URL
              value: "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
            - name: AIRFLOW_LDAP_ENABLE
              value: "no"
            - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER
              value: /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
            - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING
              value: "True"
            - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__DONOT_PICKLE
              value: "False"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            periodSeconds: 20
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            tcpSocket:
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            tcpSocket:
              port: http
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "2"
              memory: 4Gi
            requests: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /bitnami/python/requirements.txt
              name: requirements
              subPath: requirements.txt
            - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/src
              name: airflow-dags

      volumes:
        - name: requirements
          configMap:
            name: airflow-dependencies

        - name: airflow-dags
          hostPath:
            # directory location on host
            path: /Users/admin/Desktop/FXC_Airflow/dags/src
            # this field is optional
            type: Directory
---
# Source: airflow/charts/postgresql/templates/primary/statefulset.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: release-name-postgresql
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    helm.sh/chart: postgresql-11.0.6
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
  annotations:
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: release-name-postgresql-hl
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate: {}
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
      app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
  template:
    metadata:
      name: release-name-postgresql
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
        helm.sh/chart: postgresql-11.0.6
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
      annotations:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: default

      affinity:
        podAffinity:

        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
                    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
                namespaces:
                  - "default"
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 1
        nodeAffinity:

      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      initContainers:
      containers:
        - name: postgresql
          image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:14.1.0-debian-10-r80
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1001
          env:
            - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER
              value: "5432"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR
              value: "/bitnami/postgresql"
            - name: PGDATA
              value: "/bitnami/postgresql/data"
            # Authentication
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: "bn_airflow"
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: release-name-postgresql
                  key: password
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: "bitnami_airflow"
            # Replication
            # Initdb
            # Standby
            # LDAP
            - name: POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP
              value: "no"
            # TLS
            - name: POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS
              value: "no"
            # Audit
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG
              value: "off"
            # Others
            - name: POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES
              value: "error"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES
              value: "pgaudit"
          ports:
            - name: tcp-postgresql
              containerPort: 5432
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - exec pg_isready -U "bn_airflow" -d "dbname=bitnami_airflow" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - -e

                - |
                  exec pg_isready -U "bn_airflow" -d "dbname=bitnami_airflow" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
                  [ -f /opt/bitnami/postgresql/tmp/.initialized ] || [ -f /bitnami/postgresql/.initialized ]
          resources:
            limits: {}
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: dshm
              mountPath: /dev/shm
            - name: data
              mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - "ReadWriteOnce"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "8Gi"
```

The idea is that after successful deployment I would be able to access webserver UI through the localhost:30303, but can't for some reason. It feels like there should be a minor change to fix it...

For now what I've tried is to connect to the webserver pod: `kubectl exec -it <webserver pod name> -- /bin/bash` and run two commands `airflow db init` and `airflow web server -p 8080`.

Comment: There is an official Helm Chart for Airflow https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html Using that might solve your problem